# How call different Classes on button in Ui-Component. Magento2

Tags: magento2, adminhtml

I create the `ui_component` which code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">makeanoffer_edit.makeanoffer_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">makeanoffer_edit.makeanoffer_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Make An Offer</item>
         <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">makeanoffer_edit</item>
        </item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
         <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="back" xsi:type="string">PME\MakeAnOffer\Block\Adminhtml\MakeAnOffer\Edit\BackButton</item>
            <!-- <item name="delete" xsi:type="string">PME\MakeAnOffer\Block\Adminhtml\MakeAnOffer\Edit\DeleteButton</item> -->
            <item name="reset" xsi:type="string">PME\MakeAnOffer\Block\Adminhtml\MakeAnOffer\Edit\ResetButton</item>
            <item name="save_and_continue" xsi:type="string">PME\MakeAnOffer\Block\Adminhtml\MakeAnOffer\Edit\RejectButton</item>
            <item name="save" xsi:type="string">PME\MakeAnOffer\Block\Adminhtml\MakeAnOffer\Edit\AcceptButton</item>
            <!-- <item name="accept" xsi:type="string">PME\MakeAnOffer\Block\Adminhtml\MakeAnOffer\Edit\AcceptButton</item> -->

        </item>        
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="makeanoffer_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">PME\MakeAnOffer\Model\MakeAnOffer\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">makeanoffer_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">makeanoffer_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>

            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="submit_url" xsi:type="url" path="makeanoffer/index/acceptoffer"/>
                </item>
            </argument>

           <!--  <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="submit_url" xsi:type="url" path="makeanoffer/index/acceptoffer"/>
                </item>
            </argument> -->

        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="general">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string"/>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="makeanoffer_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">makeanoffer</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="product_name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Product Name:</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">makeanoffer</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Customer Name:</item>  
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">makeanoffer</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="email">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Customer Email:</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">makeanoffer</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="pnumber">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Customer PhoneNo:</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">makeanoffer</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="offer_time">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Offerd at time:</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">makeanoffer</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field> 
        <field name="message">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Customer Message:</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">makeanoffer</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="product_price">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Product Price:</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">makeanoffer</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="offeramount">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Offerd Price:</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">makeanoffer</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>        
     </fieldset>
 </form>
```

now my question is I created two **buttons** first is **Accept Offer** and other is **Reject Offer** I want to call different classes on the each class but they both call the same class because of the `submit_url` now how can I set these two buttons to call the different classes and my Second Question is if I change the name of the **Accept Button** from **save** to somthing else then it do not call my class the same issue is withe **Reject Button** as well if I change the name from "save_and_continue" to something else it do not works.

[image]